# What is the JCF Library and Where Can I find Documentation On It?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have inherited a site where the previous developer used the "JCF" library to do a lot of custom formatting and styling.  I've looked around the web for over and hour and can find no actual documentation on what the JCF library is and how it is used.  I'm not new to JQuery at all - I've just never heard of this plugin.

Does anyone know anything about it?  Code sample below:

```
jcf = {
// global options
modules: {},
plugins: {},
baseOptions: {
    useNativeDropOnMobileDevices: true,
    unselectableClass:'jcf-unselectable', 
    labelActiveClass:'jcf-label-active',
    labelDisabledClass:'jcf-label-disabled',
    classPrefix: 'jcf-class-',
    hiddenClass:'jcf-hidden',
    focusClass:'jcf-focus',
    wrapperTag: 'div'
},
```

Comment: I'm in exactly the same situation. Did you ever find the source of this library? I have no docs or anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the newest version's demo here: [http://psd2html.com/jcf](http://www.psd2html.com/js-custom-forms/)

And the up-to-date documentation at github: https://github.com/w3co/jcf

Answer (score 1):

It's the library, that has been written by service psd2html.com for styling form elements

Comment: Please add a relevant source if possible.

Comment: Without a relevant source this answer is useless

Comment: As someone who used psd2html 3 times, I can vouch for that. There was such a library for each of the markups they provided. It looks like it's their own library.

Comment: I'm also working on a site developed by psd2html. We've also been provided with this library.